# how could a check not been done with all assertions set to true?

Tags: eiffel, eiffel-studio-20.05

Running a debug session with estudio with all assertions set to true (I checked into cluster, common target, specific target, etc.) pass over a check assertion?

I also tried to remove `EIFGENs` and recompile the whole project.

[image]

Comment: Is it library code? Libraries may have their own assertion settings.

Comment: @AlexanderKogtenkov No, I was thinking about that but its a class inheriting from `WSF_FILTERED_ROUTED_EXECUTION` into the `setup_router` feature

Comment: @AlexanderKogtenkov if I `find . -name *.ecf -exec grep assertions {} \;` I get only `<assertions precondition="true" postcondition="true" check="true" invariant="true" loop="true" supplier_precondition="true"/>` results

Comment: Not all ECFs have the element `assertions`, so you can also look for the ECFs without it.